# Visual Studio 2022 17.2 and 17.3 cannot start debugger

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022

Just updated to VS 2022 17.2 and preview 17.3.
Debugger does not start, no matter how I invoke the program from within VS, neither with Core nor with Framework 4.8.
There are no error messages.

Comment: Did you restart your computer after updating?

Answer (score 1):

reloading symbols worked:

Tools > Options > Debugging > Symbols