# Visual Studio for Mac Version 17.3 Preview debugger problem on physical device

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-mac

Using, *Visual Studio for Mac Version 17.3 Preview* I get debugger problem on physical device and can't run my Xamarin app on my iPhone

It says:

> warning MT1043: Failed to launch the application using the instruments service. Will try launching the app using gdb service.
> Launching 'com.myapplicaion.applicationname' on the device 'Leos iPhone'
> Could not find the application 'com.myapplicaion.applicationname' on the device 'My iPhone'.

It could be related to the problem with Visual Studio (Windows): [Visual Studio 2022 17.2 and 17.3 cannot start debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72256486/visual-studio-2022-17-2-and-17-3-cannot-start-debugger)

Emulator works

Anyone know how I could get it to work?

---

Blank `Xamarin.Forms` project works

A new stable version was released with the problem: `Version 17.0.3 (build 21)`, I shifted to it

<strike>I will move all files and install all Nuget packages into the new blank Xamarin.Forms project</strike>

The only hint I found was a difference in `*.csproj` forms file:

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <DebugType>portable</DebugType>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

... which was missing in my project and present in the newly created project. It did not help to add it though

---

I found the the cause to be the *Entitlements.plist*. When I have it empty - the debugger works. However I need entitlements...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.developer.icloud-services</key>
    <array>
        <string>CloudKit</string>
    </array>
    <key>com.apple.developer.icloud-container-identifiers</key>
    <array>
        <string>iCloud.company.container</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I updated Xcode. Opened Visual Studio and it kept crashing, My Mac could not open other programs with Visual Studio open. I could not force quit Visual Studio.
It was stuck *Restoring packages*.
It said I should install version command line control: `sudo xcode-select --install`. Executing it said it already was installed

When verified 13.4.1 Xcode version and installing additional components. Visual Studio could be opened and run properly again.
But Im back to the original issue that debugger won't connect

Comment: What is your Xcode verison?Try to open Xcode, and check if there are any updates (the latest version is `13.4.1`), or if there are any Xcode components need to install. Then you can open Xcode, go to `Preferences->Locations`, and check Command Line Tools if is /Applications/Xcode.app .

Comment: I am facing the same problem today, have you found a solution?

Comment: @tipa
I did not need iCloud anymore so removed it. So did not find any solution